# Is it possible to access Hbase installed inside docker container to be accessed using java client on mac OSX?

Tags: docker, hbase

I created a docker container that have HBase installed in standalone mode. I used -net=host mode to run docker container. I can see UI for master and regionserver but when I am trying to connect to HBase from my java program after establishment of connection with zookeeper, it says that  This server is in the failed servers list: boot2docker:60020. I am using mac OSX and boot2docker. Please give suggestion to this. Here is my dockerfile.

```
FROM centos:6
# Install required libraries.
RUN yum install -y tar
# Install java.
RUN curl -LO \
'http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u71-b14/jdk-7u71-linux-x64.rpm'\
-H 'Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie'
RUN rpm -i jdk-7u71-linux-x64.rpm
RUN rm -f jdk-7u71-linux-x64.rpm
# Export JAVA_HOME.
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr
# Copy hbase code to docker container.
COPY hbase-*.tar.gz /
RUN tar -xzvf hbase-*.tar.gz
RUN rm hbase-*.tar.gz
RUN mv hbase-* hbase
# Copy hbase-site.xml.
ADD hbase-config-files/hbase-site.xml /hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml
# Start Hbase.
CMD ["./hbase/bin/hbase", "master", "start"]`
```

To run this container I used docker run --net=host -t docker_image